# How to skip video if button is not pressed in AS3 Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, timer

I'm working on a video ad self project in AS3. Basically the length of the video is 10 seconds. I have set a timer that on 5 seconds a 'Keep Watching' button will show and if interacted the video will continue playing. And if not, at 7 seconds it will automatically end the video. How do I prompt the video to stop playing if the button is not pressed? I am getting confused.

```
var baseTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000,1)
var isInteracted:Boolean = false;

baseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, testTimer);
btSkip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btSkipvideo);

baseTimer.start();

function btSkipvideo(e:MouseEvent)
     {
        if (!isInteracted)
     {
        btSkip.visible = false;
     }
        else
        trace("This is a testing");
     }
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just create another timer to accomplish this. So something like this:

```
var baseTimer:Timer;
var timeoutTimer:Timer;

//assuming your btSkip button is a timeline object that is not currently visible
btSkip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btSkipvideo, false, 0, true);

function startVideo():void {
    //do whatever you do to start the video

    //create the base timer to show the button after 5 seconds
    baseTimer = new Timer(5000, 1);
    baseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showBtn, false, 0, true); //use weak listener so the timer doesn't stay in memory forever
    baseTimer.start();
}

function endVideo(e:Event = null):void {
    //do whatever you do to stop the video
}

function showBtn(e:Event):void {
    btSkip.visible = true; //or however you decide to show the button

    //at this point it's been 5 seconds since the video started to play
    //create the other timer to end the video after 2 additional seconds
    timeoutTimer = new Timer(2000, 1);
    timeoutTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, endVideo, false, 0, true);
    timeoutTimer.start();
}

function btSkipvideo(e:MouseEvent){
    if (timeoutTimer) {
        //stop the timer so it doesn't end the video
        timeoutTimer.stop();
    }

    btSkip.visible = false; //or however you'd hide the button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first, I think that's better to use your video player ( `FLVPlayback` component, `NetStream` object, ... ) to get the exact time ( 5 seconds and 7 seconds ) to execute any thing because of the problem of buffering of the stream ... But just to answer your question using a `Timer` object, I think that you can use only one `Timer` to do what you are looking for :

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);  // you can set the repeat count to 7 if you want
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, on_Timer);
function on_Timer(e:TimerEvent): void {
    switch (e.target.currentCount) {
        5:  // 5 seconds, show the "Keep Watching" button
            btSkip.visible = true;
            break;
        7:  // 7 seconds, if the timer is always running, so stop the video
            stop_the_video();
            break;
    }
}

function play_the_video(): void {
    // start playing your video
    timer.start();
}
function stop_the_video(): void {
    // stop playing your video
    timer.stop();
}
btSkip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btSkipvideo);
function btSkipvideo(e:MouseEvent): void {
    timer.stop();
}
```

Hope that can help.